# Mutex captured by one thread and released by another CMSIS and FreeRTOS STM board

Tags: c, embedded, mutex, freertos, cmsis

We are having an issue with a mutex in CMSIS and FreeRTOS on an STM32F407 board.

There are two threads that can access a hardware radio via a UART. We are using a mutex to ensure only one thread can talk to the radio at a time.

Using SWO to print to the serial port every time the mutex is captured or released successfully, we can see that in certain situations the following occurs:

- Thread 1 captures the mutex successfully using osMutexWait(radioAccessMutex, 400)
- Thread 2 releases the same mutex successfully using osMutexRelease(radioAccessMutex)

From my understanding, a mutex can only be released by the thread currently holding the mutex.

The return values from both mutex calls is osOK. Recursive mutexes have been turned off in the config file. Both threads are the same priority.

Possibly relevant information:
CMSIS v. 1.02
FreeRTOS v. 8.2.1

Code for SWO output:

```
void SWO_write(char* output)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(output); i++)
    {
      ITM_SendChar(output[i]);
    }
}
```

This code is called every time the mutex is captured or released immediately following the successful call. A null terminated string is passed in with the result of the call.

Comment: I believe osMutexWait() and osMutexRelease() are not FreeRTOS functions.  Are you using CMSIS RTOS?

Comment: Why would Thread 2 even try to release the mutex without first obtaining it?

Comment: I am using CMSIS with FreeRTOS. That's a good question, and part of what we're trying to debug. The release of the mutex depends on a message arriving in a queue. We've verified that the message only makes it to the queue once, but it somehow triggers the release function twice.

Comment: CMSIS has an RTOS component that includes osMutexWait() and osMutexRelease().  I can understand that you would use the non-RTOS components of CMSIS with FreeRTOS.  But I don't understand why you would use CMSIS RTOS with FreeRTOS.  If you're using FreeRTOS then perhaps you want xSemaphoreTake() and xSemaphoreGive() instead.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the use case for CMSIS correctly. I thought it was just a wrapper around the RTOS of your choice, allowing you to switch out RTOSes if necessary. I'll try using the direct FreeRTOS calls and let you know if anything changes.

Comment: You may be right that your CMSIS RTOS implementation is a wrapper for FreeRTOS.  I probably misunderstood.  I agree with your understanding of the mutex -- only the owner thread should be able to release it.

Comment: It would probably be better to avoid the issue altogether by having a third thread that services the UART and have the two existing threads send data to that rather then having direct and contended access to the UART. Then no mutex is required at all and the behaviour will be more deterministic and easier to debug.

Comment: Is the releasing thread is of a lower priority than the acquiring thread? It could be that everything is functioning correctly, but preemption prevents the lower priority thread from printing before the higher priority thread prints.

Comment: FWIW, looking at the FreeRTOS and CMSIS online documentation, it's unclear that a mutex can only be released by the thread that owns it.  You'd probably have to dig into kernel source and see if it actually checks the owner thread ID nor not.  My personal guess is it doesn't.

Comment: @RussSchultz ; The semantics of a mutex require thread ownership, otherwise it is just a binary semaphore.  The [CMSIS-RTOS documentation](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/RTOS/html/group__CMSIS__RTOS__MutexMgmt.html#details) is not at all unclear on this.

Comment: I'm with @DKrueger ... your debugging method is suspect.  Occam's Razor suggests that the mutex mechanism relied upon by thousands of projects over a number of years is more likely to be correct that the debug mechanism you have just invented.  Your debug instrumentation and the thing you are instrumenting need to be bound in a critical section to ensure there is no preemption causing the out-or-order output.

Comment: You need to perhaps show the code that you are using to demonstrate this behaviour - that way we can see how your debugging method is flawed, because the reality is it unlikely to be  as you have described.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments everyone. Both of the threads are the same priority, but it's definitely possible our debug method is flawed. I added the function we're using for SWO output to the original question. I was just trying to come up with some way to determine what is happening without adding much latency. I agree it's unlikely that the mutex mechanism is flawed, but we have already found one verified bug with our CMSIS version on this project, so that's where we started looking. Anyway, we'll try these suggestions and update if something works.

Comment: @clifford  I agree those are the classical semantics.  It doesn't mean the RTOS implements it correctly.  Inspecting the RTX (old version and new) code it appears to check mutex ownership and return an error if not the owner.  
FreeRTOS does NOT appear to return error for cases on non-recursive mutexes (at least as far as I cared to look at the code).     Non-recursive mutexes APPEAR to be treated as semaphores, but there's a lot of `#define` indirection and abstraction of objects as queues that might be obscuring the check for ownership from me.

Comment: @RussSchultz : Regardless of the FreeRTOS semantics, the CMSIS-RTOS required semantics are clear, and the abstraction layer must adapt the underlying RTOS to conform.  FreeRTOS is "unusual" in many ways with respect to its implementation, but the CMSIS-RTOS specification is a facade layer intended to provide common and consistent semantics and API.  Personally I'd avoid both FreeRTOS and CMSIS-RTOS, but that is a different issue.

Comment: @CLIFFORD  I'll disagree that the semantics are clear in the CMSIS-RTOS documentation.  While it does say mutexes introduce ownership, and the owner can recursively obtain, it doesn't state anywhere a non-owner cannot release.  The return values of `osMutexRelease()` don't include 'non-owner' as a potential error (RTX implementation just returns `osError`, which actually isn't listed as a possible return value in the documentation).   We all assume only owners can release a mutex, because it's a generally accepted semantic of mutexes, but...

Comment: I added a new mutex to test if one thread could capture it and another could release it. I checked the values in the debugger and it appears that CMSIS/FreeRTOS does allow this behavior. The call in thread 1 to capture the mutex succeeds, and the call in thread 2 to release the mutex also succeeds, both with osOK. It would seem it is not guarded against. These two locations are the only areas where the mutex is ever changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration of CMSIS and FreeRTOS that we are using does allow one thread to release a mutex that was captured by another thread.

I added a new mutex to test if one thread could capture it and another could release it. I checked the values of each call in the debugger and both return osOK. CMSIS/FreeRTOS does allow this behavior. These two locations are the only areas where the mutex is ever changed.

Answer (score 0):

CMSIS doesn't require that the thread that acquires the mutex is the same as the one that releases it. From the [CMSIS-RTOS](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/cmsis/RTOS/html/index.html) Documentation of `osMutexRelease`:

> osStatus osMutexRelease   (   osMutexId   mutex_id    )
>
> Release a Mutex that was obtained with osMutexWait. Other threads that
>   currently wait for the same mutex will be now put into the state
>   READY.
>
> **Status and Error Codes**
>
> - osOK: the mutex has been correctly released.
> - osErrorResource: the mutex was not obtained before.
> - osErrorParameter: the parameter mutex_id is incorrect.
> - osErrorISR: osMutexRelease cannot be called from interrupt service routines.

Note that there is no error code for the condition when different threads acquire and release the mutex.

Having the same thread acquire and release a mutex is good design, but it's not enforced by CMSIS.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. It's interesting that this isn't spelled out in the documentation, but must be inferred by the lack of a specific error code. Either way I'm glad to see some evidence to back up our results. Thanks again!